# React - enable/disable component when we click on one img

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to show only one of `FarmStakingCard` when I click on the img `logoCake` and disable the other `FarmStakingCard` or if I click on the `logoCake2` show only the second `FarmStakingCard` and disable the first one

```
const showCakeStats = () => {
        return 'CAKE';
      }
    
      const showCake2Stats = () => {
        return 'CAKE2';
      }
    
            <img src={logoCake}  width={100} height={100} onClick={() => showCakeStats()} />
            <img src={logoCake2}  width={100} height={100} onClick={() => showCake2Stats()}/>
           
          </HorizontalBlock>
          <br/><br/><br/>
          <div>
    
            <FarmStakingCard cakeBalance={cakeBalance} cakePrice={CAKEPrice} />
            <FarmStakingCard cakeBalance={cake2Balance} cakePrice={CAKE2Price} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a state to control this:

```
const [cakeShow, setCakeShow] =  useState() 

const showCake = (val) => {
  setCakeShow(val)
}

<img src={logoCake}  width={100} height={100} onClick={() => showCake("CAKE")} />
<img src={logoCake2}  width={100} height={100}onClick={() => showCake("CAKE2")}/>
     
{cakeShow === "CAKE" && <FarmStakingCard cakeBalance={cakeBalance} cakePrice={CAKEPrice} />  }
{cakeShow === "CAKE2" && <FarmStakingCard cakeBalance={cake2Balance} cakePrice={CAKE2Price} />  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be code missing, but you could do something along the lines of

```
const [showCakeState, setShowCakeState] = useState(true);
    
            <img src={logoCake}  width={100} height={100} onClick={() => setShowCakeState(false)} />
            <img src={logoCake2}  width={100} height={100} onClick={() => setShowCakeState(true)}/>
           
          </HorizontalBlock>
          <br/><br/><br/>
          <div>
    
            {showCakeState && <FarmStakingCard cakeBalance={cakeBalance} cakePrice={CAKEPrice} />}
            {!showCakeState && <FarmStakingCard cakeBalance={cake2Balance} cakePrice={CAKE2Price} />}
```

This will show FarmStakingCard1 if state is true, otherwise it will only show FarmStakingCard2